# ASP.NET make a panel visible on click of hyperlink (whilst also cuasing postback for page navigation)

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages

I may be asking the impossible but let me set out my problem:

I have a menu in a MasterPage which uses images and mouseover mouseout events for design purposes.
On one of the menu options I need to display a set of sub menus options on the click of the parent menu item.  The menu item itself also needs to navigate to a specified url.

I was originally trying to use an AJAX accordion panel but as I only had one accordion panel it was always displaying the sub menu items and was not collapsing.

I have also tried putting the options in a div and setting the display via javascript.  This worked but then was overwritten once the page navigation postback occurred.

Here is the source:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Src="LeadHeader.ascx" TagName="LeadHeader" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/LeadFooter.ascx" TagName="LeadFooter" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
var revert = new Array();
var inames = new Array('home', 'whoweare', 'whatwedo','ourapproach', 'ourvalues', 'contact');


// Preload
if (document.images) {
  var flipped = new Array();
   for(i=0; i< inames.length; i++) {
    flipped[i] = new Image();
    flipped[i].src = "images/"+inames[i]+"2.jpg";

  }
}

function over(num) {
  if(document.images) {
    revert[num] = document.images[inames[num]].src;
    document.images[inames[num]].src = flipped[num].src;

  }
}

function out(num) {
  if(document.images) document.images[inames[num]].src = revert[num];
}


function ShowHide(elementId)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(element.style.display != "block")
    {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function UpdateText(element)
{
    if(element.innerHTML.indexOf("Show") != -1)
    {
        element.innerHTML = "Hide Details";
    }
    else
    {
        element.innerHTML = "Show Details";
    }
}



    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                <uc1:LeadHeader ID="LeadHeader" runat="server" />
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div id="nav">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href="Default.aspx">
                        <img src="Images/home.jpg" alt="home" id="home" onmouseover="over(0)" onmouseout="out(0)"
                            class="right" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <a href="AboutUs.aspx">
                        <img src="Images/whoweare.jpg" alt="who we are" id="whoweare" onmouseover="over(1)"
                            onmouseout="out(1)" class="right" /></a>
                </div>
            <%--   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <cc1:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" AutoSize="None" FadeTransitions="true"
                    TransitionDuration="350" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" >
                    <Panes>
                        <cc1:AccordionPane runat="server">
                            <Header>--%>
                                <div class="menu-item">
                                    <a href="WhatWeDo.aspx">
                                        <img src="Images/whatwedo.jpg" alt="what we do" id="whatwedo" onmouseover="over(2)"
                                            onmouseout="out(2)"   class="right" onclick="ShowHide('divDetails');UpdateText(this);"  /></a></div>

                           <%--/Header>
                            <Content>--%>
                         <div id="divDetails" style="display:none;">

                            <a href="management.aspx" title="Management Development">Management Development</a><br />
                                <a href="leadership.aspx" title="Leadership Development">Leadership Development</a><br />
                                <a href="personal.aspx" title="Personal Development">Personal Development</a><br />
                                <a href="realteams.aspx" title="Team Building / Facilitation">Team Building & Facilitation</a><br />
                                <a href="coaching.aspx" title="Coaching">One to One Coaching</a>
                          </div>

                        <%--    </Content>
                        </cc1:AccordionPane>
                    </Panes>
                </cc1:Accordion>
               --%>

            <div class="menu-item">
                <a href="OurApproach.aspx">
                    <img src="images/ourapproach.jpg" alt="our approach" id="ourapproach" onmouseover="over(3)"
                        onmouseout="out(3)" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item">
                <a href="OurValues.aspx">
                    <img src="images/ourvalues.jpg" alt="our values" id="ourvalues" onmouseover="over(4)"
                        onmouseout="out(4)" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item">
                <a href="ContactUs.aspx">
                    <img src="images/ContactUs.jpg" alt="contact us" id="contactus" onmouseover="over(5)"
                        onmouseout="out(5)" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
            <uc2:LeadFooter ID="LeadFooter" runat="server" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too much code, Helen! Show us the relevant HTML and JavaScript instead of just dumping the contents of a file on our laps :)

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly you need the nav buttons to direct you to another page and open a sub-menu to display further options.

The easiest way to do this would be to create the entire sub menu on the master page and hide it in your global style sheet. Each page could then contain a line of css to show the appropriate panel no JavaScript required.

A more efficient way would be to use this.Master.Page.FindControl("myPanelId") to manupulate the necessary item server-side.

I can't visualize exactly what you are doing but I have used jQuery accordion menus to do something similary. My server side code built a nested unordered list with links and the appropriate images. I let the hover event switch the accordion panel so that I could still click on any of the links to go to the corresponding page. If this is closer to what you want I can give you a general idea of the code / css necessary.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks apocalyse9,

In the end I placed my sub menu in a separate panel as suggested and then handled the visibility in the code behind, not ideal but I couldn' figure out an alternative at the time.  I am having to pass a visibility flag in the url (?expand=true) to control this.

I will investigate JQuery as that sounds like a far better solution. Would the visibility remain following postback with jquery?